# About public final void

Tags: java

i am a new to java . there is something new pops up called  public final void. what does that do ? what is the difference between public static void and public final void? I would be greatly appreciated from guys!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public final void method() {}
```

This method is `final`, and so can't be overrided in a subclass.

```
public static void method() {}
```

This method is `static`, and so is class-scoped. You can't use class attribute in this method (unless if they are `static`), and you call it using `MyClass.method()` instead of `anInstance.method()`.

Finally, `void` is the return type of the function (meaning the method returns nothing) and `public` is an *access modifier*.

**Related questions:**

- [About *access modifier*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private),
- [About `final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012167/java-final-modifier),
- [About when to use `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods).

Answer (score 4):

That must be a part of method:

public - meaning it could be accessible by any other object

static - meaning it could be accessed by class name in addition to object as well.

void - meaning that method wont return any value. It will do some operations 
within the method.

final - Meaning you cant override the method in your sub class.

Comment: static could be accesed by object name also

Comment: @rzysia - Well, the compiler (at least in an IDE like eclipse) will show a warning - *static methods should be accessed in a static way* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind - I believe ;) Quote from oracle tutorial: `Note: You can also refer to static fields with an object reference like
myBike.numberOfBicycles
but this is discouraged because it does not make it clear that they are class variables.`

Answer (score 2):

The **final** keyword is used for variables when they are constant, their value can be set only once, furthermore a final method cannot be subclassed.

**static** members belong to the class instead of a specific instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a method `final`, subclasses of your class will not be able to override it.

When you declare a method `static` you can call it without creating an object of class.