# Cannot override the final method from AbstractInputMethodService

Tags: android, abstract-class

I have a service class that extends InputMethodService. When i want to bind this service to my ActivityMain, at code below i get the "Cannot override the final method from AbstractInputMethodService" error.

```
public class MyIME extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

 //some code here...
@Override
public IBinder onBind( Intent intent ) {

    return binder;
}
```

What is this error and how to fix it?

Comment: as stated by the message, you can not override a `final` method..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java final modifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012167/java-final-modifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is this error

[`onBind()` is declared as `final` in `AbstractInputMethodService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/AbstractInputMethodService.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29). You cannot override it.

> and how to fix it?

Delete your `onBind()` method.