# Is 'println()' a static member function of PrintStream class or instance member function?

Tags: java

Here:

```
System.out.println("Hi, this is frist program");
```

Is `println()` a static member function of `PrintStream` class or instance member function?

As told by my teacher : that when there is dot (`.`) after class name then definitely we are trying to access the static member of the class.

As here out is static reference variable and it has reference of PrintStream class. So my question is that is the `println()` function has necessarily to be a static member function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `println` is an instance method of the `PrintStream` class. It is `out` that is a static member of the `System` class.

```
System.out
      ^--^
        static member of the class System, returns a PrintStream instance

System.out.println(...)
          ^------^
            instance method of PrintStream
```

[`out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is declared as

```
public static final PrintStream out
```

in the class `System`, so it is a static member and you access it with `System.out` (refer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012167/java-final-modifier) for the `final` modifier).

[`println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println--) is an instance method of the `PrintStream` class declared as

```
public void println()
```

Comment: what does `final` mean?

Comment: @Infinity Good question, I linked to another question that goes in-depth about that.

Answer (score 1):

No, `println` is an instance method of `PrintStream`, as you can see in the Javadoc of `PrintStream`.

> void java.io.PrintStream.println(String x)

`System.out` gives you a reference to a `PrintStream` instance for which `println` is executed.

Answer (score 1):

`println()` is a **non static** (instance) member function of `PrintStream` class.

`out` is a **static** reference to an object of type `PrintStream`, inside `System` class.

`out` is a reference, `out.prinln()` refers to the instance method of `out`. In this case `out` is also a static member of another class, but this doesn't make any difference to the `println()` method

Answer (score 0):

It's an instance method.

`System.out` is a static reference to a `PrintStream` instance.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out
and this provides multiple overloaded versions if `println` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)