# Why am I getting a compiler error trying to switch a non-primitive integer constant?

Tags: java, switch-statement, primitive-types

This is my `switch` statement:

```
    switch (aXxx.actionType()) {
        case Xxx.TYPE_A:
            break;
        case Xxx.TYPE_B:
            break;
        case Xxx.TYPE_C:
            break;
        case Xxx.TYPE_D:
            break;
    }
```

And this is my constant declarations (defined on another class, `Xxx`):

```
    public final static Integer TYPE_A = 610921;
    public final static Integer TYPE_B = 610922;
    public final static Integer TYPE_C = 610923;
    public final static Integer TYPE_D = 610924;
```

Seeing this, my compiler (I'm using IntelliJ-based Android Studio 2.1) refused to compile my code saying:

> Constant expression required.

I can't understand the reason why; those *are* constants and I *did* initialize their values (unlike the case on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant)).

I tried changing their type to primitive `int`, the error disappeared and my code compiled just fine.

But what's the real reason behind this?

***p.s.***, *For those who are wondering why I don't use `enum`s for this: I work on Android and I'm intending to use those constants as [`@IntDef`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/IntDef.html) values.*

Comment: A variable of type `Integer` is not a constant expression even if its initialization expression is.

Comment: I thought it's the `final static` attribute that makes an expression "constant"?

Comment: Not quite. See the rules [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28).

Comment: I see. Thanks for clearing that out. You might want to post an answer instead though so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: That's not necessary. @RC found an appropriate duplicate.

Comment: public final static Integer TYPE_A = 610921; is object and final keyword is for object reference and not for content of object which can be changed which does not make it immutable. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012167/java-final-modifier and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655012/how-final-keyword-works.