# error: cannot assign a value to final variable characterName: this.characterName = characterName;

Tags: java

```
    public String swapHead(String characterName) {
  String originalCharacterName = this.characterName;
  this.characterName = characterName;
  return originalCharacterName;
  }
}
```

How can I make this code work? What does the error message mean?

Comment: It means you declared `characterName` as final. If you want to change it, don't declare it final.

Comment: Final variables cannot be reassigned a value. They need to store a value at the time of declaration, and once they are assigned, the stored value cannot be changed.

Comment: Have you tried this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012167/java-final-modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `this.characterName` has a `final` modifer, so it can not be re-assigned. You can remove the `final` modifier.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful!