# Can I keep a variable read-only in Java? It'a all ok in compile time or runtime

Tags: java

I'm a Java newbie. I want to make some variable read-only in some special scope.how can I do it?
Can I add some rules of grammar? Or there are any way work？

sample：

```
public void func(Object obj); // how can i make variable obj read-only?
```

Comment: All you can do is to declare it `final`, to prevent reassignment. That doesn't mean you can't mutate it, though.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "read-only"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java final modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012167/java-final-modifier)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void func(final Object obj);
```

When a variable is declared with the final keyword, its value can’t be modified. That means a reference variable declared final can never be reassigned to refer to a different object.

The data within the object can be changed. the state of the object can be changed but not the reference.

Comment: The value can be modified, if the object was an array, you could assign a new value to one of the indexes. The variable obj cannot be reassigned.

Comment: That's correct. To be precise, a reference variable declared final can never be reassigned to refer to a different object.

Answer (score 1):

make the method look like this:

```
public void func(final Object obj) {...}
```

inside of the method body you can only read the variable but cannot assign any value to is. so its read-only.
(**final** means, that you can only assign once an value to an variable
-> final double pi = 3.14159265359d; )

Comment: you can't reassign it, but if it's a mutable datatype, you can change it value

Answer (score 1):

Change it to `public void func(final Object obj);` .

But be cautious, the object itself can still be changed.
See this example:

```
List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
System.out.println(list);//[1,2,3]
foo(list);
System.out.println(list);//[1,2,3,4], the list was mutated.
....
public void foo(final List<Integer> list){
   list.add(4);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a variable as `final` e.g. `final MyClass obj = aVal` to prevent assigning something other than the first assignment. However, note that `obj` can still be modified i.e. `obj = someOtherVal` is not possible but you can do `obj.setX(...)` if there is a setter method `setX` in `MyClass`.

The only way both re-assignment and modification can be prevented is by defining the class as immutable and then declaring a variable of it with the keyword, `final`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an object with final keyword to func(Object obj).

Please check below sample example

```
public class FinalExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        FinalExample ex = new  FinalExample();
        
        A a = new A();
        a.setI("Test");
    
        ex.func(a);
        
    }
    
    public void func(final A a) {
        
        System.out.println(a.getI());
    }
    
}


public class A {

    public String i;

    public String getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(String i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    
}
```